# How to find and replace the first n appearances with sed?

Tags: bash, sed

I have been using this code, to replace the first occurrence of a pattern in a file:

```
sed "0,\#pattern#s##replacement#" input.txt > output.txt
```

To replace the first 5 occurrences of a pattern in a file, I used this:

```
sed "0,\#pattern#s##replacement#" input.txt > output1.txt
sed "0,\#pattern#s##replacement#" output1.txt > output2.txt
sed "0,\#pattern#s##replacement#" output2.txt > output3.txt
sed "0,\#pattern#s##replacement#" output3.txt > output4.txt
sed "0,\#pattern#s##replacement#" output4.txt > output5.txt
mv output5.txt output.txt
```

How can I more simply replace the first `n` appearances of a match with `sed`?

Answer (score 4):

This is not really a natural job for `sed` (personally I'd used `awk`) but the following should work:

```
 sed '1{x;s/.*/00000/;x};/PATTERN/{x;s/0//;x;t1;b;:1;s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/}'
```

The length of the string of `0`s in the first `s` command is the number of replacements; I used `0` with the intention of generating the `sed` command as follows:

```
 sed "1{x;s/.*/$(printf %*d $COUNT 0)/;x};
     /$PATTERN/{x;s/0//;x;t1;b;:1;s/$PATTERN/$REPLACEMENT/}"
```

With Gnu `sed`, you can replace `t1;b;:1;` with `T;`

Here's the awk version:

```
 awk 'N&&sub(PAT,REPL){N--};1' N=5 PAT="pattern" REPL="replacement"
```

Comment: Now *there's* the way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

`sed` has no natural counting ability. You could do something weird like this.

```
sed -r '
  /pattern/ {
    s//replacement/
    x
    s/.*/&x/ 
    t clear
    : clear
    s/x{3}/&/
    x
    T
    q
  }
' file
```

In the last substitute command, set the number of `x`'s to the number of substitutions you want. In practice this command would need to be used with `-i` to modify the file in place since it quits and stops processing the file after it performs the requested number of substitutions.

The above with comments:

```
sed -r '
  /pattern/ {
    s//replacement/
    x          # exchange spaces
    s/.*/&x/   # increment number of x s
    t clear    # reset the successul substitition flag
    : clear    
    s/x{3}/&/  # test for the required number of x s to quit
    x          # exchange spaces
    T          # if substitution was not successful, next cycle
    q          # quit
  }
' file
```

Here's another idea, but it can only go up to 10 replacements.

```
sed -r '
  1{x;s/^/0/;x}
  /pattern/ {
    s//replacement/
    x
    y/0123456789/1234567890/
    tx :x   # reset substitution flag
    s/3/&/
    x; T; q
}'
```

If you're using a `sed` that doesn't have the `T` command, it can be replaced with it's opposite, the `t` command. Change:

```
T
q
```

to

```
t quit
b
: quit
q
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider perl:

```
perl -lpe 's#pattern#s##replacement# and $n++ if $n < 5' input
```